# TYPO3: Hook after creating or editing page

Tags: hook, typo3

I'm searching for a hook which is called after page creation or changes on pages like "`hide page in nav`", "`deactivate page`" or "`move/delete page`"

Does someone know of one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These Hooks are located in [t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/classt3lib___t_c_emain.html)

The following are just some of those:

- processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray
- processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray
- hook_processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations
- processDatamap_afterAllOperations

In your case, i think you could use "**processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray**".

Example how to include it in your **ext_localconf.php**:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = 'EXT:your_extension/hooks/class.tx_yourextension_tcemain.php:tx_yourextension_tcemain';
```

Example class:

```
<?php
    class tx_yourextension_tcemain {
            function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$pObj) {
                if($table == 'pages' && $status =='new') {
                    // do some stuff
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

With **$table**, you can check which table is modified. **$status** allows you to retrieve the current action, for example "new", "update" or "delete".

Example for TYPO3 > 6 with namespaces on another hook:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/tslib/class.tslib_menu.php']['filterMenuPages']['YourExtension\\Hook\\FilterMenuPages'] = 'EXT:your_extension/Classes/Hook/FilterMenuPages.php:YourExtension\Hook\FilterMenuPages';
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the way i have also found now after hours of search and testing. One little change, i use the `processCmdmapClass` Hook and the `processCmdmap_deleteAction` i the case of deletion.

Comment: [This is the updated link for t3lib_tcemain.php (typo3 4.5)](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/classt3lib___t_c_emain.html)

Comment: Thank you, i added it to my post.

Comment: The hook changed in TYPO3 6 `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['YourExtension\\Hook\\FilterMenuPages']`

Answer (score 6):

For **TYPO3 7.6** version (Also Works in 10.4.X as well)

> Write following in **ext_localconf.php**

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['extkey'] = 'Vendor\\Extension\\Hook\\TCEmainHook';
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['extkey'] = 'Vendor\\Extension\\Hook\\TCEmainHook';
```

> Create hook class **/Classes/Hook/TCEmainHook.php**, Choose appropriate function from below list

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Hook;

class TCEmainHook {
    public function processCmdmap_preProcess($command, $table, $id, $value, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processCmdmap_postProcess($command, $table, $id, $value, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(array &$fieldArray, $table, $id, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processCmdmap_deleteAction($table, $id, $recordToDelete, $recordWasDeleted=NULL, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processDatamap_afterAllOperations(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, array &$fieldArray, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
    public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations($status, $table, $id, array $fieldArray, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a extension [dmc_hooklist](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dmc_hooklist/) which list all hooks. (used a few years ago)

Or have an look into t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php there are the hooks you need.

Comment: i wonder, why my answer was not usefull? Explanation possible?

Comment: Hi, the dmc_hooklist is the "standard" answer but this extension doesn't work on my system. You have given the first information on google if someone is searching in this topic. I wanted to find out more details or best practices. thanks anyway