# Creating Hooks to an extension in TYPO3 6

Tags: php, hook, typo3, tt-news

I'm trying to create a hook to `news` extension in TYPO3 6. The hook is created for an extension but not from an extension.

I created a directory called `Hooks` in `typo3conf/ext/` directory. My hook is `/typo3conf/ext/Hooks/tx_news_tceMain.php`

```
class tx_news_tceMain{
function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$reference)
{
    if($table='tx_new_domain_model' && $status='new')
        mail('email@me.com','News added!','Body!');
}
}
```

I did not give any namespaces here.

So basicallly every time a news record is `saved and viewed`, a mail is sent.

I registered the hook in `news/ext_localconf.php`

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = 'EXT:Hooks/class.tx_tt_news_tceMain.php:tx_tt_news_tceMain';
```

This is not working! Am I doing it right ? Is there a way I can debug this ?

Comment: I think your hook function has the wrong signature - here is an example. It has an $status parameter, which makes using $GLOBALS unnecessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526428/typo3-hook-after-creating-or-editing-page

Comment: Oh, and you hook into the extension "news", not "tt_news". They are different!

Comment: I made the necessary changes, It's still doesn't. Is there a way I can Debug this ?

Comment: Have you checked that the function is actually called (there is a `die()` function in php). Oh, and please do wrap this hook in an extension, although it may have just this few lines of code. An extension is created with very few clicks and the structure is much cleaner. Following administrators of this site will be thankful!

Comment: Thank you all for the reply.It's finally working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot just create an extension directory. You need to create at least an `ext_emcomf`. And install the extension in the extension manager.

Otherwise TYPO3 won't find the extension.

Comment: Thank you :) It worked when I do it from an extension itself.