# How can I hook into the creation of a tca record?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I want to run code whenever a new tca record is created. Is there a hook I can use?

What i want do do:

I have products. Each product has many nutritions.
Every time I create a new Product I want to generate a set of default nutritions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several hooks, that you can use while operating on records in BackEnd, take a look i.e.: for **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13526428/1066240)**.

*Sorry, as your question is very broad, I won't give you any samples.*