# TYPO3 - send "Your Account has been activated"-mail to user

Tags: typo3, user-accounts, activation

I'm just playing around with FELogin and Formhandler. So far I got a nice registry-page with some basic content and after I submit the registration, the admin (in this case it's myself ^^) gets a notification about that....something like "New registration, Username XYZ, please active him". The useraccount is not active at this point.

The idea (and the point where I m currently struggeling) is that the admin now goes into the backend and activates that user account via the lightbulb. Immediatly after that the user get's an email like "Your account is now active, feel free to use it".

Is this somehow possible at all?

Thx!

Update
First of all: thanks Jost for the answer. I tried that by myself but I guess I m still missing something.

So I figured out that you need to extend the ext_localconf.php and this file no longer exits within > Typo3 v6.2.
But I could add a file called AdditionalConfiguration.php within /typo3conf/ and I added these lines

```
    <?php 
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][]  =
    '/fileadmin/stuff/php/dummy.php:tx_EXTENSIONNAME_tcemainprocdm';
    ?>
```

Next step: create the dummy.php and added this:

```
    <?php
    class tx_EXTENSIONNAME_tcemainprocdm 
      {    
        function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray ($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$reference) 
         {    
           echo "Do something with with id $id";
         }
      }
    ?>
```

But nothing happend...neither by clicking the frontend nor changing stuff in the backend. Maybe I m on a complete wrong track or maybe I just missed something. Nevertheless I would like to avoid to edit or create new files within the /typo3conf/ext/ if that's possible. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the the TCEMain-Hooks. They are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526428/typo3-hook-after-creating-or-editing-page#answer-13584255), with an example.

You can use the hook `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray`. It is called every time a record is updated in the backend. You can get details about the kind of operation, the modified table, fields and so on from the arguments that are given to the function.