# TYPO3 hook for saving page settings

Tags: typo3

I'm searching for a hook which is called after **page settings** saving or change. I tried this answer [TYPO3: Hook after creating or editing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526428/typo3-hook-after-creating-or-editing-page), but it does something else.

Does someone know of one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was solving this problem a week ago. You have to have a class `ProcessCmdmap` in folder `Extension/Classes/Hooks/ProcessCmdmap.php` which is called by hook, and this class should have a method which is called by the save. I recommend this method `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray`

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Hooks;

class ProcessCmdmap {

    public function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, array &$fieldArray, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {  
        var_dump($id);
        var_dump($table);
        var_dump($status);
        var_dump($fieldArray);
        var_dump($pObj);
    }  
}

?>
```

And dont forget to register your hook:

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][''] = 'Vendor\Extension\Hooks\ProcessCmdmap';
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][''] = 'Vendor\ Extension\Hooks\ProcessCmdmap';
```