# Typo3 extension - Property should be invisible in the BE like the Uid of each record

Tags: typo3

So basically i need a property in my Typo3 extension models that is in visible in the Backend. It shouldn't be directly changeable by the BE user. More or less like the `Uid` property (like with `getUid()` of each model i should also be able to access the property BUT i want this property to als to get setter).

Basically every time the BE user saves the record (editing or creating it) the property (bool) should be changed to true, while i want to set this property to false whenever a Scheduler task runs. How do i define such a property?

Comment: It looks like you want to implement a way to determine if content has been edited since ... Probably there is an easier way to do this. If you say what you really want to acchieve (better in a new question) you might get answers that are more to the point.

Comment: Well, i accomplished to change the property called "edited" to 1 whenever the record has been edited in BE thanks to a hook... At this point everything went smoothly, but for gods sake, i can't make that field invisible in the BE while creating or editing a record. That'd be the last step needed.

Comment: Problem solved... I just changed the 'type' for this property in the TCA files to "passthrough". That way the field isn't displayed in the BE, but the property can be changed by my hook (to 1) and via my Scheduler task after it's been run (to 0) with it's corresponding setter. Interesting enough I cannot change the datatype of "edited" to boolean in PHPMyAdmin, it uses tinyint automatically. Even though it works for me, it's not as "elegant" as it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you can define a field as readonly, so a BE user can not edit it by default:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA'][$yourTable]['columns'][$yourField]['config']['readonly'] = 1;
```

if you want to hide it you simply do not include the field in the "showRecordFieldList" (or any palette mentioned there)

```
$GLOBALS['TCA'][$yourTable]['interface']['showRecordFieldList'] = 'all visible fields or palettes;
```

---

Second: you need to write a hook for the datahandler so any modification to a record will set your field to true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it seems that there is MUCH i still need to learn, because i have no idea how to work with hooks and the official typo3 documentation is sadly not nearly enough to make a typo3 newcomer understand it. I know this sounds lazy, but do you have any link to a step by step hook tutorial? Because it seems i don't even understand the basic concepts of it, just that you can somehow implement and run you own code in a predefined typo3 method. But where to even start? I have no idea.

Comment: you might try the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526428/typo3-hook-after-creating-or-editing-page) or [this Website](https://daniel-siepmann.de/Posts/2016/07/21-how-to-find-typo3-hook.html)

Comment: After a long trial and error phase, i accomplished my task thanks to your help. Thanks a lot.