# Modify fields in setter of domain model TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3-9.x

In my extension I would like to modify input data if the data records are saved in the backend module.
E.g. geo coordinates are to be generated from the address data.

I thought I could do this in the setter method of the address field in the domain model, but the setter is not called at all on saving.

Otherwise, creating and editing the data in the backend module works perfectly.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: For modifying data after update from BE you should use hooks, @see other question and answers about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526428/typo3-hook-after-creating-or-editing-page

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

I've solved it with evaluation classes, see: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#eval

Comment: Good old TCA ;) Good to know it works, you can answer your own question so it will create knowledge base for others.

Comment: If you just need the geo coordinates, there is an extension for that: https://github.com/ujamii/ujamii-geocoder